# Checking validity of a dynamically generated query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am generating a query string dynamically which i want to execute only if it is avalid query (valid syntax). Otherwise i want to skip that query and continue pl sql execution. How can it be done?

Comment: Enclose it by `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END;`

Comment: You can also try [`DBMS_SQL.PARSE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i997676), which will do the semantic check and **execute** the SQL as well, if the syntax is valid.

Comment: Will it slow down execution if large no of queries are being checked in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Nest that query execution with another BEGIN..EXCEPTION..END; .In exception, handle "WHEN OTHERS". In case there is any syntax error, it will be caught in exception block and next line of your logic in pl/sql execution will be moved on to.